# При обновление страницы, сбрасываются (вкладки)таба, как это можно исправить?

Tags: javascript

Я почти не знаю javascript и поэтому решить данную проблему я не смогу без вашей помощи в написания кода. Как сделать так, чтобы при обновление страницы, открывалась именно та вкладка, которая была активна до обновления страницы. Нужно изменить данный код.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.tabs-box {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.tabs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    height: 42px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #00655c;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.tabs li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0 21px;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 42px;
    border-top: 1px solid #00655c;
    border-left: 1px solid #00655c;
    border-right: 1px solid #00b7a6;
    background-color: #009688;
    color: #ddd;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px
}
.tab_last {
    border-right: 1px solid #00655c;
}
ul.tabs li:hover {
    background-color: #26A69A;
    color: #fefefe;
}
ul.tabs li.active {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    border-top: 2px solid green;
    display: block;
}
.tab_container {
    border: 1px solid #00655c;
    border-top: none;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: auto;
}
.tab_content {
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
}
.tab_content p {
    margin-bottom: 10px
}
.tab_content img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="container">
       <!-- Базовый контейнер вкладок(табов) -->
        <div class="tabs-box">
           <!-- Список вкладок -->
            <ul class="tabs">
                <li class="active" rel="tab1">Вкладка 1</li>
                <li rel="tab2">Вкладка 2</li>
                <li rel="tab3">Вкладка 3</li>
                <li rel="tab4" class="tab_last">Вкладка 4</li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Контейнер для блоков с содержанием -->
            <div class="tab_container">
                <!-- Блок вкладки с содержанием -->
                <div id="tab1" class="tab_content" style="display: block;">
                    <h2>Содержимое Вкладки 1</h2>
                </div>
                <!-- конец #tab1 -->
                <div id="tab2" class="tab_content" style="display: none;">
                    <h2>Содержимое Вкладки 2</h2>
                </div>
                <!-- конец #tab2 -->
                <div id="tab3" class="tab_content" style="display: none;">
                    <h2>Содержимое Вкладки 3</h2>
               </div>
                <!-- конец #tab3 -->
                <div id="tab4" class="tab_content" style="display: none;">
                    <h2>Содержимое Вкладки 4</h2>
                </div>
                </div>
                <!-- конец #tab4 -->
            </div>
            <!-- конец .tab_container -->
        </div>
        <!-- конец .tabs-box -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // вкладки с содержанием
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        $(".tab_content:first").show();
        /* в режиме вкладок */
        $("ul.tabs li").click(function () {
            $(".tab_content").hide();
            var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
            $("#" + activeTab).fadeIn();
            $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
        /* дополнительный класс tab_last, 
        чтобы добавить границу к правой 
        стороне последней вкладки. */
        $('ul.tabs li').last().addClass("tab_last");
    </script>
    <!-- /.container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Как вариант можно попробовать сохранять значение вкладки в window.location.hash, а при загрузке страницы проверять есть ли там значение, если есть то сразу открывать нужную вкладку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        // вкладки с содержанием
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $(".tab_content:first").show();

    // если при загрузке страницы есть значение хеша то пробуем включить нужную вкладку
    if (window.location.hash) {
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        $(window.location.hash).fadeIn();
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
        $("[rel = " + window.location.hash.slice(1) + "]").addClass("active");
    }

    /* в режиме вкладок */
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function () {
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
        // Записываем значение rel выбранной вкладки в хэш
        window.location.hash = activeTab;
        $("#" + activeTab).fadeIn();
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
    /* дополнительный класс tab_last, 
    чтобы добавить границу к правой 
    стороне последней вкладки. */
    $('ul.tabs li').last().addClass("tab_last");
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, работает. Удачи вам в жизни!!!